# Is there a way when Painting Weights to select the joint to paint influences on in the viewport?

Tags: maya

I rememeber there being a way to bypass having to select the joint in the influences list - instead you just click the joint you want to paint in the viewport.

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the joint → **Select Influence**